# React app changes not reflecting when application deployed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, kubernetes

Hi I have react application deployed in kubernetes. I am facing some issues in my application. when I make some changes in code, for example lets say I have added some console.log its not appearing in browser when deploy my code. Below is my configuration of dockerfile

```
# syntax = docker/dockerfile:1.2

FROM node:17-alpine as builder

ENV NODE_ENV=production
ARG NODE_AUTH_TOKEN
ARG NEXUS_AUTH_TOKEN

WORKDIR /src

ENV PATH /src/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

COPY .npmrc ./
COPY package.json ./

COPY ./ ./

RUN npm i -f --production

RUN npm run build --silent

RUN rm -f ./.npmrc

COPY . .
# Expose port
EXPOSE 3000
# Start the app
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

Below is my .env file

```
REACT_APP_NOLOGIN=1
REACT_APP_ENTITY_TYPE=''
REACT_APP_ENTITY_CODE=''
REACT_APP_POST_LOGOUT_URI=''
FAST_REFRESH=false
```

Below is my package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "jest --coverage",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
```

Below is my deployment file

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment 
metadata: #Dictionary
  name: #{KUBERNETES_WEB_APP_NAME}#
spec: # Dictionary
  replicas: 1
  strategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
    rollingUpdate:
      # maxUnavailable will set up how many pods we can add at a time
      maxUnavailable: 50%
      # maxSurge define how many pods can be unavailable during the rolling update
      maxSurge: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: #{KUBERNETES_WEB_APP_NAME}#
      instance: #{KUBERNETES_APP_INSTANCE}#
  template:  
    metadata: # Dictionary
      name: #{KUBERNETES_WEB_APP_NAME}#
      labels: # Dictionary
        app: #{KUBERNETES_WEB_APP_NAME}#  # Key value paids
        instance: #{KUBERNETES_APP_INSTANCE}#
        product_id: app
        app.kubernetes.io/component: app
        app.kubernetes.io/name: app
      annotations:
        vault.security.banzaicloud.io/vault-role: #{KUBERNETES_NAMESPACE}#
        prometheus.io/path: /metrics
        prometheus.io/port: "80"
        prometheus.io/scrape: "true"
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: default
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
      containers: # List
        - name: webapp-container
          image: #{WEB_IMAGE_TAG}#
          #command: ["sh", "-c", "echo $mypassword echo going to sleep... && sleep 1"]
                    imagePullPolicy: Always
          ports: 
            - containerPort: 3000
          resources:
            requests:
              memory: "2Gi"
              cpu: "1300m"     
            limits:
              memory: "2Gi"
              cpu: "1500m"
```

These are my configurations. When i make some changes in the code and deploy my changes not appearing but strange thing what i observed in when I check my file in source in browser i can see my changes but those changes does not reflect in browser. Latest code changes I see in file in source. I am not sure any problem with compiling or any other issues. Struggling to find out issue since two days. can someone help me to fix this? Thanks a lot

Comment: One of possible reasons could be just caching the react js files by the server or the browser. A common practice is adding [app's version number to referenced js files](https://medium.com/@coder.mansi.thakur/prevent-caching-for-javascript-files-in-your-web-application-a6deb1f25200).